# repeat scripts in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html and javascript code. I would like to see the script part (the alert) repeated.

```
<div id='ItemsContainer' ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='Controller'>
      <div ng-repeat='item in items' >
        {{item}}
        <script>alert("{{item}}");</script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.log = function(m) {
        console.log(m);                
    };    
    $scope.items = [1, 2];
}
```

Is this possible using angularjs?

Comment: You can create a custom filter and have the alert inside the filter function

Comment: you can call javascript functions using the {{ }} syntax, so you could just call a function in your controller?  Perhaps this is an over- simplification of your actual need?  I only say this because what you've show doesn't seem very angularjs?

Comment: It's an oversimplification indeed. What I'm trying to achieve is to repeat some javascript in an angularjs ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items | filter: alertItem' >

function alertItem(item) { alert(item) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand question, I create [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3282/) with my variant:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat='item in items' ng-init="alertFunc(item)">
          {{item}} 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.log = function(m) {
        console.log(m);                
    };    
    $scope.items = [1, 2];

    $scope.alertFunc = function(item){
        alert(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx from this angularjs newbie! this seems to satisfy my needs for now.